# Vector calculus - Green's Theorem image

Tags: greens-theorem

I'm working on the circulation form of Green's Theorem in a math textbook and came across this image. Of course, I understand r is the parametrization of C but the figure has what look like non-tangent vectors labeled r coming out of C. Does anybody know what the orange and blue vectors represent? Or should they just not be in the figure?

[image]

Comment: I would like to know the answer to this question as well. I know for sure that the light blue vectors indicate the tangential vectors.